# C# Outlook PST folder click event

Tags: c#, event-handling, outlook-addin

I'm trying to find a way to capture a Mouse Click event on a folder inside a PST.

I've looked for events on `Outlook.Folder` interface but there is none that applies :(

Is there a way to accomplish this ? Thank you

Comment: What are you trying to do? Modify / intercept the context menu?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko I want to fire a webpage inside outlook webbrowser when the user clicks a specific PST folder.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. The Outlook object model provides the following events for the Explorer class:

- [BeforeFolderSwitch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868537.aspx) - is fired before the explorer goes to a new folder, either as a result of user action or through program code. Note, the event handler may cancel the action setting the boolean parameter to true.
- [FolderSwitch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865625.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) - is fired when the explorer goes to a new folder, either as a result of user action or through program code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display a webpage for a particular folder, Then you need to set the MAPIFolder.WebViewURL and WebViewOn properties.